# iOS 13 - Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT (CoreFoundation)

Tags: ios, crash, core-foundation, ios13

I have started getting huge number of the crash reported from `Fabric` for my iOS application which is already distributed on the App Store. Crashes are started reporting from `18 Sep` onwards for `iOS 13` only. Here is the crash log for the main thread which is getting crashed.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x185180408 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_0 + 4
1  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
7  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18525bd68 __CFStringCollectionCopy.cold.1 + 14
```

Anyone facing a similar crash? How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: iOS 13 has not been in beta since 19 Sep.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the info. I am updating the question.

Comment: @rmaddy is there anything I need to do or I just need to wait until Apples fix as the crash is in CoreFoundation?

Comment: IS your app compiled with SDK 12 or 13 ?

Comment: @CZ54 I have used xcode 10.1 for building ipa with deployment target 9.0

Comment: @CZ54 do you have any idea? This crash has reduced my crash free user under 30%. I have seen in Fabric that in last update of Apple `13.1.1` the crash is even increased a lot. :(

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Were you able to fix this?

Comment: @Raspu we didn’t do any code change. It was automatically fixed. I assume Apple pushed some patch. I recommend you to build with xcode 11.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Awesome, that's good news for us, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As par Alex's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58218610/1084174),

> It seems that the dyld3 saves the generated clojure files in the app
> tmp directory and if you use NSFileProtectionComplete the closure
> files have this property too.
>
> To generate a crahs close the app, lock the phone, send a push that
> will wake up the app and then the crash is generated.
>
> The solution seems to be simple, just change the permissions for the
> app tmp direcptry to
> **NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication** and the app will
> not crash. I really don't know why apple did this.

This worked for me.

### Reproduction & Test

Rayns comments

> You don't necessarily need to use push notifications to reproduce the
> issue. If your app is configured to use complete file protection in
> the entitlements, any code that runs while protected data is
> unavailable will cause the app to crash. For example, my company's app
> has a background task that takes longer than 10 seconds to execute.
> Since protected data becomes unavailable around 10 seconds after
> locking the device, the app will crash before the background task can
> finish executing (despite having more time available on the
> assertion).

Answer (score 0):

My app has same situation.
After I change data protection to "Complete until first user authentication", my app is no more crash about it.

Comment: Could you please explain how did you change "Complete until first user authentication"?

Comment: See this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements and  https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev88ff319e7 if you manage everything through XCode.

Comment: If the issues are related I've a post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215486/debugging-sporadic-app-crashes-with-dylib-in-ios13-ipados-13 where there are some links to the Apple Developer forum as well.